# Why crypto.createHash returns different output in new version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, backwards-compatibility, node-crypto

**Problem**

I have node.js module that is using `crypto.createHash` to generate `md5` hash.

Recently I noticed that hash generated by `crypto` module is different in new versions:

**Code**

```
require('crypto').createHash('md5').update('¥').digest('hex')
```

**Node.js v0.10.0**

Outputs: `ab3af8566ddd20d7efc9b314abe90755`

**Node.js v6.1.0**

Outputs: `07625e142e4ac5961de57472657a88c1`

**Question**

I was wondering what causes that in new version and how can I solve this?

**Update**

Similar issues on GitHub:

- https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6813
- https://github.com/node-xmpp/client/issues/206

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Some inputs in Node v6+ calculate a different hash than previous Node versions.

Basically, when you pass a string to `.update()`, with Node versions before v6 the default encoding was `binary`, but for Node v6 that changed to `utf-8`.

For example, take this code:

```
require('crypto').createHash('md5').update('¥').digest('hex')
```

This outputs `ab3af8566ddd20d7efc9b314abe90755` on Node pre-6 and `07625e142e4ac5961de57472657a88c1` on Node 6.

If you want Node 6 to output the same as pre-6 versions, you have to tell `.update()` to use `binary` encoding:

```
require('crypto').createHash('md5').update('¥', 'binary').digest('hex')
```

Or the other way around (make Node pre-6 output the same as 6):

```
require('crypto').createHash('md5').update('¥', 'utf-8').digest('hex')
```

Comment: Are these encodings(binary/utf-8) differs by in-char byte order?

Comment: @vp_arth not so much byte _order_, but the way they are represented in bytes differs. I believe that `binary` is Latin-1 encoding (which is limited in the number of characters that it can represent, which I guess was the reason why the default changed to `utf-8` for Node v6).

Answer (score 4):

Just like mark this issue in github:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6813 is about the default encoding for digests that was changed to `utf8` in v5/v6 and in v4 and earlier it was `binary`