# HMAC changes according to node version (paybox module)

Tags: node.js, hash, hmac, node-crypto

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/paybox and I need to upgrade my node version (from 5.6 to 6+)

As you can see below, the `generateHMAC` creates a hash that differs if I change my version of node.

Can you help me understand this, and tell me if it can compromise something (maybe it is OK? several hashes could be OK?)

Here is my code snippet:

```
"use strict";
const paybox = require('./node_modules/paybox/lib/paybox.js')

let computed_hmac = paybox.generateHMAC({a:12}, 'aaaaaaabbbbbbbcccccccc1111122233');
console.log(computed_hmac);
```

Here is the result with version 5.6.0 of node

```
$ node -v
v5.6.0
$ node testPaybox.sh
D0643202B4AF2A23055933597ACB6CB024A26F7DEBC4798B5AB0AC6242D1C9D0F1BC481B86CEF0505546D1D30F4A6807D193A00E5A4E81F874447BC0EE040D87
```

and with any version from 6.11.1 (up to the latest)

```
$ node -v
v6.11.1
orange:easy-sport-web dao$ node testPaybox.sh
E5A70879F038F35103524AB5157205C8169DDBAD3B41465D19690F87C64FACB6E098C283812B6D6AC79F23AE7A7DC2B0EEEDF5796E4BFC9DE87A517AFCE7E049
```

Comment: Reason: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37445613/1816580, you will probably have to fork it and adjust it.

Comment: It seems that it is not the problem. I have reduced it to a key encoding issue. I have created a new post here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45533172/1566975?sem=2

Could you have a look @ArtjomB.?

Comment: Please read that answer again. It seems you haven't understood where the difference is.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I have tried it and it seems it has nothing to do. I have added the encoding and I have the exact same result:

changed `.update("hey")` into  `.update("hey", 'utf-8')` to specify the encoding

See my comment in the question https://stackoverflow.com/q/45533172/1566975?sem=2

Comment: @ArtjomB. to stick with https://stackoverflow.com/a/37445613/1816580 I have added the encoding to the `update` call in https://stackoverflow.com/q/45533172/1566975?sem=2, and the result is the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45582931/1566975 prefer using the fork https://github.com/daohodac/node-paybox that solves the issue